# How to save firefox addons for offline installation

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, firefox-extensions, offline-files

I wish to save firefox addons & extenstions and install it offline, Is it possible to save the addons and install it later offline?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

On the Firefox addon page search for your desired addon.

**Download Addon**

1. Continue to download
2. Right-Click -> Save Link As... -> save the [.xpi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPInstall) file

[image]

**Installing Addon**

Drop the addon in the adress bar.

Comment: pretty elegant, and dosen't need preinstalled extentions. Nice!

Comment: unfortunately I dont know the exact term for "save as shortcut" for Firefox. Feel free to edit.

Comment: Added a screenshot

Comment: @Journeyman wow nice work, which program have you used?

Comment: [licecap](http://cockos.com/licecap/) by cockos - been itching for a chance to use this ;p

Answer (score 2):

Possible. If you need only the Add-ons to be saved & install offline, you may refer below steps. Or if you're planning to do a full backup, you can also refer [Journeyman Geek's](https://superuser.com/questions/646856/how-to-save-firefox-addons-for-offline-installation/646858#646858) Answer.

1. These files are usually [.xpi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPInstall) or [.jar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_%28file_format%29) files.
2. Download the file to your local computer.

[image]

3. At the top of the Firefox window, click on the <kbd>Firefox</kbd> button, and
   then click `Add-ons`. The Add-ons Manager tab will open.
4. In the Add-ons Manager tab, select the `Extensions` panel.
5. To add the downloaded add-on to the list of available add-ons, drag
   and drop the file into the Add-ons window. The Add-on is added to
   the list.
6. The installation process should begin.

That should get your work done.

Source: **[Mozilla Support](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/unable-install-add-ons-or-extensions?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Unable%20to%20install%20add-ons#w_you-are-asked-to-download-the-add-on-rather-than-installing-it)**

Answer (score 1):

[febe](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/febe/) will do the trick - you can both back up things as a single xpi file, or individually.

I haven't used it recently so I can't remember if it backs up settings. Some folk seem to report issues backing up, but that seems to be an issue with permissions more than anytbing else. The nice thing is this is an extention, and I believe cross platform.

For windows, if you want a full backup of your mozilla firefox or thunderbird environment, or more than just xpi files, take a look at [mozbackup](http://mozbackup.jasnapaka.com/). Its a third party bit of software that does more complete backups. Its what I use now.